# Find all possible combinations of maximum eight (8) keys in this dictionary, only if the values of those keys add up to 45

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, combinations, key-value

Here is what I have so far:

```
import itertools as it

allNotesDict = {"C": 1, "Db": 2,  "D": 3,
"Eb": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6,
"Gb": 7, "G": 8, "Ab": 9,
"A": 10, "Bb": 11, "B": 12}

combNotes = list(it.combinations(allNotesDict, 8))
```

I have tried itertools. I have been thinking of using an if-statement with multiple conditions, but haven't.
I expect to see a list of lists of keys (in the case of my dictionary "notes")

Answer (score 3):

You already did most of the logic, the only thing needed is to select combinations which add up to 45. You can do this using a generator expression and the `sum` function like below:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

allNotesDict = {"C": 1, "Db": 2, "D": 3, "Eb": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6, "Gb": 7, "G": 8, "Ab": 9, "A": 10, "Bb": 11, "B": 12}
combNotes = list(itertools.combinations(allNotesDict, 8))

result = []

for comb in combNotes:
    if sum(allNotesDict[i] for i in comb) == 45:
        result.append(comb)

pprint(result)
```

Comment: Small note: this code actually uses a [generator expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions/) and not a list comprehension - which is actually probably more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have updated the answer to reflect this.